# Create AAR from a Module having AAR dependencies

Tags: java, android, aar

I have a module dependencies in a project and that module already has some AAR as dependencies. I want to export this module as AAR but if I do so then the reference to internal libraries is not getting resolved. In short AAR inside AAR is giving issue. So I want to know if AAR can have AAR inside as dependencies ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Create AAR using another AAR file and jar inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405465/android-studio-create-aar-using-another-aar-file-and-jar-inside)