# Packaging spring sub-projects into one jar

Tags: java, spring, gradle, jar

I'm having Spring based web-app that I'm trying to bundle into a single jar.

My thoughts on laying out the project was to have a root project that contains multiple sub-projects, where there would be one sub-project that is a spring-boot application, and others sub-projects maybe my own-written code handle certain business logic let's say.

So the structure may look something like:

```
/root
 build.gradle <- the problem is here, how I should write root project build script
 /spring-backend-subproject
 /other-business-subproject
```

Having all these sub-projects, I want to package them all into one single JAR, so that I can just do

```
java -jar build/libs/RootJar.jar
```

otherwise I need to run:

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

which will run the particular main class in the "spring-boot" sub-project

I've been searching online for how to bundle all subproject jars into one jar, such as this one: [Can Gradle jar multiple projects into one jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782013/can-gradle-jar-multiple-projects-into-one-jar) 
but I often just end up having errors such as main-class not found(which does not happen if I run the jar specifically in the "spring sub-project" folder) or SpringApplication class not found (again does not happen if run jar in the sub-project folder)

How may I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this pattern extensively. Instead of trying to put the deployment classes into the root, add a module (I usually call it `-launcher`) that lists the other modules as dependencies and contains your main class and related application code, such as any `application.properties` you may have.

This module will produce an artifact `my-project-launcher.jar`, and you deploy this to whatever platform you're using.

Comment: but I can't get one jar